# How to connect my app to parse in android studio

Tags: parse-platform

I unzip the SDK named Parse-1.9.2 and dragged all files into the libs folder present in app folder. Then added the following code in build.gradle(Module: app)

dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
}

After that I don't get how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not new to android development, it would be easy for you to set up parse sdk to your android project using the steps provided in the parse.com website. If your are new to android development, follow one of these,

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Building-Data-driven-Apps-with-Parse

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-simple-login-and-signup-tutorial/